# Delete predicates from the list in Prolog

Tags: lambda, prolog

I want to delete all predicates named `a` from the list. The result must be as shown below:

```
?- delete_all(a(_), [a(1),a(2),a(3),b(1)], R).
R = [b(1)]
```

Please, do not offer me built in solutions of SWI or others, because the code must be in Amzi-Prolog.

Thanks.

Edit: I have tried the following code but it is working properly only for atoms:

```
remove_all(X,[],[]).
remove_all(X,[X|L],R):-remove_all(X,L,R).
remove_all(X,[Y|L],R):-not(X=Y), remove_all(X,L,M), R=[Y|M].

?-remove_all(a(_), [a(1),a(2),a(3),b(1)], R).
R=[a(2),a(3),b(1)]
```

which is not true :(

Comment: I have tried the following code:
`remove_all(X,[],[]).
remove_all(X,[X|L],R):-remove_all(X,L,R).
remove_all(X,[Y|L],R):-not(X=Y), remove_all(X,L,M), R=[Y|M].`

But it removes only atoms.

Comment: edit your post with that code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use findall

```
findall(X, (member(X,[a(1),a(2),a(3),b(1)]),\+(X=a(_))) ,V).
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you said no swi-prolog. However it's an easy task (compared to the main one), to implement a recursion that behaves the same as the `exclude/3` used, the rest should be ISO prolog or present in amzi too. It uses [lambda.pl](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl), a library that allows easier higher order programming:

```
:- [lambda].
filter(Term, List, Result) :-
    Term =.. [Pred|Args],
    length(Args, Arity),
    exclude(\X^(X =.. [Pred2|Args2],
                length(Args2, Arity2),
                Pred == Pred2,
                Arity == Arity2), List, Result).
```

This solution has the advantage of staying away from the unpure `findall/3`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Little fix, and it should work:

```
% remove_same_indicator(+Callable,+List,-List)
remove_same_indicator(_, [], []).
remove_same_indicator(X, [Y|L], R) :- 
       functor(X, F, N), 
       functor(Y, F, N), 
       !, 
       remove_same_indicator(X, L, R).
remove_same_indicator(X, [Y|L], [Y|R]) :- 
       remove_same_indicator(X, L, R).
```

Let's give it a try:

```
?- remove_same_indicator(a(_), [a(1),a(2),a(3),b(1)], R).
R = [b(1)]
```

Advantage over findall solution, one does not loose variables.
For example one can do:

```
?- remove_same_indicator(a(_), [a(A),a(B),a(C),b(A)], R).
R = [b(A)]
```

But with the findall solution we get:

```
?- L=[a(A),a(B),a(C),b(A)], findall(X, (member(X,L),\+ (X = a(_))), R).
L = [a(A), a(B), a(C), b(A)],
R = [b(_I)]
```

The argument of b is not anymore bound to A, since findall
creates copies and thus new variables.

Bye

functor/3 is ISO and also in Amzi!
http://www.amzi.com/manuals/amzi/pro/ref_manipulating_terms.htm#functorTermFunctorN

Comment: Well whats point in making facts with variable inside such as a(A)? it will be always true...

Comment: Facts with variables are very useful, check out tic-tac-toe: http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/prod/en/docs/05_run/06_bench/09_programs/11_tictactoe/01_tictactoe.p.html , move/3 and win/2 are such facts.

Answer (score 0):

```
remove_all(_, [], []).
remove_all(X, [Y|R], L):- \+ X \= Y, remove_all(X, R, L).
remove_all(X, [Y|R], [Y|R2]):- X \= Y, remove_all(X, R2, L).
```

Comment: (assuming that by "predicates named a" you mean terms with functor a/1)